# Actualizar datos con espacios en varias columnas y eliminar caracteres raros en sql

Tags: sql

Hola tengo una tabla con **username**, **lastname** pero en mi tabla me han introducido muchos valores que tienen espacios y caracteres raros, como pudiera eliminar estos espacios y caracteres.

Otro problema es que los campos **username** y **lastname**  han dejado entre los dos nombres o apellidos dos espacios en blanco y deben ser solo uno.

Ejemplos

1-

```
username: Natalia  lastname: Merca  Dona   ///Deberia ser Merca Dona
```

2-

```
username:Enrico  Ferrer lastname:Mantis    //Deberia ser Enrico Ferrer
```

He probado `UPDATE mdl_user SET firstname  = LTRIM(RTRIM(firstname))` para borrar al inicio y final pero no se agregarle el lastname para hacerlo en un solo query y que tambien me deje un solo espacio intermedio cuando hay dos nombres o dos apellidos

Gracias

Comment: Lo mejor para evitar que te introduzcan 2 espacios es controlarlos directamente en el input del usuario, lanzar un evento cada vez que el usuario escribe algo en el input y comprobar que si el ultimo carácter es un espacio no dejar poner otro.

Comment: ¿Que base de datos estás utilizando? ¿y que versión?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En caso de querer eliminar algún carácter de tu string podrías utilizar `replace()` como en este ejemplo : `update tuTable set username = replace(username,'#',''), lastname = replace(lastname,'#','');`
Aquí eliminarias de todos tus registros el caracter `#` aunque no es algo automatizado.

Si quisiera automatizar tu proceso de caracteres en vez de ejecutar varios `replace()` podriás crear una función como la siguiente : https://gist.github.com/jgdoncel/bc20b39b8cd612c4a26dfcaf3bb14dd8

Para eliminar espacios los espacios en blanco `update tuTable set username = trim(username), lastname = trim(lastname);`

Para no tener que comprobar siempre los registros, puedes crear un `trigger` que antes de la inserción de los valores te elimine los espacios a los laterales y deje siempre un espacio en medio de las palabras :

```
delimiter $$
create trigger bi_elimina_espacios before insert on tuTable for each row
begin
    declare parte1 varchar(255);
    declare parte2 varchar(255);
    if (new.username like '% %') then
        set parte1 = substring_index(new.username," ",1);
        set parte = substring_index(new.username," ",-1);
        set new.username = trim(concat(trim(parte1)," ",trim(parte2)));
        set new.lastname = trim(new.lastname);
    else
        set new.username = trim(new.username);
    end if;
end;
delimiter $$
```

Comment: Hola ya por ahi tengo una solución , para el caso que tenga dos espacios en el username entre los dos nombres: Leo  Luis

Comment: Perdona, no te he entendido, dices que solo tienes solución para los espacios? O que la solucion no te sirve si tiene dos espacios???. Si te refieres al espacio en medio ejecuta un `replace` como dije. Si necesitas ayuda con los espacios en medio te creo una fucnion y te envio el codigo.

Comment: Hola ya tengo solucion para los espacios al inicio y final y con el codigo que me madas para los caracteres tambien.lo que me quedaria seria los espacios en el medio

Comment: Una funcion para eliminar un espacio entre los nombres me ayudaria mucho pues tengo muchos usuarios con dos espacios entre los nombres. Saludos y gracias

Comment: De acuerdo, te acabado de actualizar la respuesta con un trigger para la eliminacion de espacios laterales. Sobre los espacios entre palabras ahora te daré repuesta.

Comment: Te acabo de modificar el trigger para tu problema con los espacios entre palabras

Answer (score 0):

En MySql a partir de la versión 8.0 puedes utilizar expresiones regulares con funciones nativas, para versiones anteriores de MySql puedes utilizar alguna librería como [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp):

- Para quitar dos o mas espacios consecutivos de la columna `username`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(username, '[[:space:]]{2,}', ' ')
FROM tabla;
```

- Para quitar todos los caracteres excepto las letras y los espacios de la columna `username` (puedes agregar otros caracteres que quieras omitir):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(username, '[^a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+', '')
FROM tabla;
```

Con la función `trim()` quitas espacios al princio y al final de la cadena especificada como parámetro.

Si quieres actulizar la tabla tendrás que hacer un `UPDATE`, además podrías utilizar un `trigger` al insertar y actualizar para modificar el valor antes de guardarlo en la base de datos, como ha mencionado @alexci en su respuesta.